# Can prometheus support efficient exponentially weighted running averages and other online algorithms?

Tags: architecture, prometheus

Exponentially weighted running averages can be more efficient than linearly weighted ones because you don't need to keep a window of recent samples. You just store the current value of the running average and act on it with each incoming sample. Such algorithms are sometimes called "online". There's a lot of them, and I'm only using running average here as an example. In general, what's needed is a way to look at one sample per iteration whilst propagating some state between iterations. (There's also the delicate matter of getting started when there's no state yet, for instance, you might start with a very fast decay rate and ramp it down to the desired decay rate over the first few samples.)

Looking at the prometheus docs and source code, I only see functions that act on a window of recent history without any state being propagated from earlier history. This is inefficient where an online algorithm is available because every sample in the window needs to be considered every time the output is calculated. But perhaps I'm just looking in the wrong places.

Does anybody know if there's any architecture in prometheus that would make it easy to implement online algorithms for the sake of generating alerts?

Comment: If I understand what you want here (and this might very much not be the case), there is nothing like that, because Prometheus doesn't have "current values". Every time you execute a query, it is accompanied with timestamp for results to be returned (sometimes it is automatically uses current time).

Comment: But you might attempt something of that manner with recording rules and use of `offset` operator. Something of the manner `my_metric * 0.5 + 0.5 * my_ewma offset 1m or my_metric`

Comment: Hmm. Just gonna check that out. Thanks.

Comment: This will suit my purposes if I can emit a tuple from a single recording rule. I can't find a full reference to the rules language tho. Just sparse examples. Basically I wanna do this: https://fanf2.user.srcf.net/hermes/doc/antiforgery/stats.pdf

Comment: You cannot "emit a tuple from a single recording rule", you'll need multiple rules for this. (Unless we are talking about labels. If so - "tuple" is possible). Syntax of recording rules [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/). expression is any valid Prometheus query: querying syntax described [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/).

Comment: Not sure how labels help. I can append a label to the name of my recording, but the expression for each label variant is completely independent of the others, I think? I suppose I can compute stuff that goes into all of them as yet more recordings, but they'd clutter the interface and occupy memory. Is there such a thing as a private recording that can only be seen by other recordings or alerts?

Comment: I meant that if your tuple is based of different values of an input metric labels, it can be done in single rule (In fact it'd be done automatically). ".. private recording .." - no. Best you can do, is separate rules into different files, but in the UI, it all will be united.